# URLLoader does not resond to .close()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My application requires that I am able to abort/close a URLLoader instance at any point in the post-connect stage; that is, regardless if I have connected and the file transfer has already begun, or whether I have connected, and the file transfer has yet to commence (the server has not begun sending the file yet).

Here is my code:

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("myText.txt"));
```

This is what I have noticed:

When I connect to a server, and the server starts sending the file immediately, DURING the actual file transfer, if I invoke myTextLoader.close(), it aborts immediately. This is expected. I can monitor this by executing the SWF in Firefox,and noticing that when I issue the close(), the network connecion goes from Pending to aborted.

However, if I connect to the server, and the file transfer has not actually begun yet (I have confirmed the connect event has fired, and the server has simply not begun sending the file), then myTextLoader.close() has no effect. Only AFTER the first bytes start being transferred from the server, will .close() have any effect. I can verify the connection is stuck in Pending in Firebug.. .close() has no effect until the transfer has started.

Any ideas how to work around this issue? I need to be able to invoke .close() and have the connection torn down regardless of the connection stage.

Comment: This apparently is a known issue: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3982000 with no workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3rd party AS3 HTTPClient (https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient) appears to not exhibit this issue with close().

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would think of, is create a bool "aborted" that is set to true where the close() method is invoked.
Like :

```
function abort():void {
     _aborted = true;
     myTextLoader.close();
}
```

Then check for its value anywhere in the onProgress event or any similar event, to actually call the URLLoader close() method again whenever its value is true...

```
function onProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
     if (_aborted) {
           myTextLoader.close();
     }
}
```

Its not a pretty thing and is an ugly workaround, but this could work, since when the first bits are actually received, you'll know if you already wanted to close it or not.

Did you find any bug report on that anywhere ?... I doubt it could be an intended behavior...

Comment: I have not found a bug report on it... perhaps I should file one :) But in your answer, you say 'when the first bits are actually received, you'll know if you already wanted to close it or not'. I do not want to wait for the first bits, as they make take minutes to arrive because of the long-polling nature of the connection.

Comment: What about if you will "abandon" the URLLoader instance e.g. - unregister all listeners and nullify it after issuing close, that way you can use another instance and this one can linger in the background waiting for first bits to load.